# What is the interest rate for Chinese yuan at the moment?

Tags: interest-rate, china

I can't seem to find any info about it on the net.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized. The answers would get out of date too quickly on a question like this.

Comment: I think they are looking for a place they can look up the interest rate at any moment. That's what the answer is anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah actually, i found it.

http://www.global-rates.com/interest-rates/central-banks/central-banks.aspx